# How do you view the console in Xcode3 without switching to Debug view?

Tags: xcode, developer-tools

I know you can see the console in debug view at the bottom, but I want to see it in the project view as well.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but you can make Xcode show the debugger console automatically when you start a debug session by going to the Debugging section of the Xcode preferences and setting the value of the **On Start** popup to **Show Console**.

Comment: A good start, but not quite.  Maybe this is a limitation of Xcode?